# Can't find my mistake

Tags: python

The compiler keeps saying this `IndentationError: expected an indented block`, but I can't find my mistake. Please help a Python newbie.

```
class BackgroundUploadFTP(threading.Thread):

    def __init__ (queueFTP):    

    def run(queueFTP):

         while True :

            if(len(queueFTP)!= 0):
                 meinftp = ftplib.FTP("altes-vennhaus.de")
                 meinftp.login("altes-vennhaus.de","XXXXX")         
                 directory = '/bilder' #ftp-Hauptverzeichnis  
                 meinftp.cwd(directory) #Wir nutzen das Hauptverzeichnis des ftp-Servers.

                 meinftp.storbinary('Stor '+'altes-vennhaus.jpg', queueFTP.popleft()) #Es wird die Datei mit
                 # dem Namen test.txt aus dem Hauptverzeichnis des Servers in die lokale
                 # Datei mit dem Namen test2.txt im Verzeichnis E:/ geschrieben.    
                 file.close()
                 meinftp.quit() #"höfliches" Trennen meinerseits der ftp-Verbindung
```

Comment: In python, white spaces are not ignored. They are part of the syntax.

Comment: Try adding an (indented!) 'pass' statement after the 'def(__init__)' line. Python wants something there.

Comment: better change your posted credentials ... !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def __init__ (queueFTP):
    # code here should be indented
```

Or maybe you meant to leave `__init__` blank?

```
def __init__(queueFTP):
    pass
```

Comment: Why cant i just leave it empty (i come from C# where an init is required empty or not)

Comment: @LukasVolpers It's syntactically not allowed. You can just put `pass` there to indicate you want it to do nothing.

Comment: @LukasVolpers you cant leave it empty, you need a `pass`

Comment: An explicit `__init__` is not required in Python.  Some ancestor class will have an implementation.

Comment: @arshajii - OP says 'i come from C# where an init is required empty or not'.  I'm explaining that that's not the case in Python.

Answer (score 1):

You have no code at all in your `__init__` method.  If you don't need a specialized `__init__`, don't define one.  If you do need one, then that code must be indented.  Adding an indented `pass` statement as a placeholder will fix your immediate syntax problem, but it's pointless.

Answer (score -1):

You can't have an empty method this confuses the compiler as it is expecting an indented block
You can get around this if you use the [`pass`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#pass-statements) statement

```
def __init__ (queueFTP):
  pass                   # this allows you to have a method that does nothing
```

Or you could also delete this method entirely, its not required.
You'd be left with this:

```
class BackgroundUploadFTP(threading.Thread):
  def run(queueFTP):

    while True :
      if(len(queueFTP)!= 0):
        meinftp = ftplib.FTP("altes-vennhaus.de")
        meinftp.login("altes-vennhaus.de","XXXX")          
        directory = '/bilder' #ftp-Hauptverzeichnis  
        meinftp.cwd(directory) #Wir nutzen das Hauptverzeichnis des ftp-Servers.

        meinftp.storbinary('Stor '+'altes-vennhaus.jpg', queueFTP.popleft()) #Es wird die Datei mit
        # dem Namen test.txt aus dem Hauptverzeichnis des Servers in die lokale
        # Datei mit dem Namen test2.txt im Verzeichnis E:/ geschrieben.    
        file.close()
        meinftp.quit() #"höfliches" Trennen meinerseits der ftp-Verbindung
```

Answer (score -1):

In python, white spaces are not ignored. They are part of the syntax. If you know Java/C/C++ , here is an analogy: every {} block in java is represented using adding one [space] before the line.